# Transactional annotation not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

@Transactional not working in Spring Boot.

**Application.java :**

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------- Start Application ---------------------------");
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.buhryn.interviewer.models" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/interviewer");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**CandidateDao.java**

```java
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class CandidateDao implements ICandidateDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public CandidateModel create(CandidateDto candidate) {
        CandidateModel candidateModel = new CandidateModel(candidate.getFirstName(), candidate.getLastName(), candidate.getEmail(), candidate.getPhone());
        getCurrentSession().save(candidateModel);
        return candidateModel;
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel show(Long id) {
        return new CandidateModel(
                "new",
                "new",
                "new",
                "new");
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel update(Long id, CandidateDto candidate) {
        return new CandidateModel(
                "updated",
                candidate.getLastName(),
                candidate.getEmail(),
                candidate.getPhone());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {

    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```java
@Service
public class CandidateService implements ICandidateService{

    @Autowired
    ICandidateDao candidateDao;

    @Override
    public CandidateModel create(CandidateDto candidate) {
        return candidateDao.create(candidate);
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel show(Long id) {
        return candidateDao.show(id);
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel update(Long id, CandidateDto candidate) {
        return candidateDao.update(id, candidate);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        candidateDao.delete(id);
    }
}
```

**Controller.class**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/candidates")
public class CandidateController {

    @Autowired
    ICandidateService candidateService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CandidateModel show(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return candidateService.show(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CandidateModel create(@Valid @RequestBody CandidateDto candidate, BindingResult result) {
        RequestValidator.validate(result);
        return candidateService.create(candidate);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public CandidateModel update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @RequestBody CandidateDto candidate, BindingResult result) {
        RequestValidator.validate(result);
        return candidateService.update(id, candidate);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        candidateService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

When I call create method in DAO system throw **exception**:

```java
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: save is not valid without active transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

My **Gradle** file :

```gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'interviewer'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13")
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.8.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final")
    compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4")
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

And link to git repository : https://github.com/Yurii-Buhryn/interviewer

Comment: Where/how do you call the `@Transactional`method? Can you add that piece of code to the question?

Comment: @mhlz Added and also path to git repository : https://github.com/Yurii-Buhryn/interviewer

Comment: You've defined spring-data-jpa in your gradle file, yet you implement your dao layer by hand, why would you do that? You don't need to define sessionFactory, entityFactory and all that, just extend `JpaRepository<CandidateModel, Long>` in your `ICandidateDao`, annotate it with `@Repository`, remove your `CandidateDao` implementation and be done with it

Comment: You are using JPA and as such should use the `JpaTransactionManager` and not the `HibernateTransactionManager`. Also why use plain hibernate if you can simply do it with JPA? You are just making things more complex. Also you are using Spring Boot then use spring boot and let it auto configure things for you instead of you working around that and configuring everything manually.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First you are using Spring Boot then use Spring Boot and let that auto configure things for you. It will configure a datasource, entitymanagerfactory, transaction manager etc.

Next you are using the wrong transaction manager, you are using JPA so you should use the `JpaTransactionManager` instead of the `HibernateTransactionManager` as that is already configured for you you can simply remove the bean definition for that.

Second your `hibernate.current_session_context_class` is messing up proper tx integration remove it.

### Use auto-config

When you take all this into account you can basically reduce your `Application` class to the following.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan("com.buhryn.interviewer.models")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------- Start Application ---------------------------");
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        if (emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

Next add an `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` containing the following.

```
# DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/interviewer

# General JPA properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

# Hibernate Specific properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

This will configure the datasource and JPA correctly.

### Use JPA instead of plain Hibernate

Another tip instead of using the plain hibernate API simply use JPA that way you could remove the bean for the `SessionFactory` as well. Simply change your dao to use an `EntityManager` instead of a `SessionFactory`.

```
@Repository
public class CandidateDao implements ICandidateDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public CandidateModel create(CandidateDto candidate) {
        CandidateModel candidateModel = new CandidateModel(candidate.getFirstName(), candidate.getLastName(), candidate.getEmail(), candidate.getPhone());
        return em.persist(candidateModel);
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel show(Long id) {
        return new CandidateModel(
                "new",
                "new",
                "new",
                "new");
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel update(Long id, CandidateDto candidate) {
        return new CandidateModel(
                "updated",
                candidate.getLastName(),
                candidate.getEmail(),
                candidate.getPhone());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {

    }
}
```

### Adding Spring Data JPA

And if you really want to benefit add Spring Data JPA into the mix and remove your DAO completely and leave only an interface. What you have now would be moved to a service class (where it belongs IMHO).

The whole repository

```
public interface ICandidateDao extends JpaRepository<CandidateModel, Long> {}
```

The modified service (which is now also transactional as it should and all business logic is in the service).

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CandidateService implements ICandidateService{

    @Autowired
    ICandidateDao candidateDao;

    @Override
    public CandidateModel create(CandidateDto candidate) {
        CandidateModel candidateModel = new CandidateModel(candidate.getFirstName(), candidate.getLastName(), candidate.getEmail(), candidate.getPhone());
        return candidateDao.save(candidate);
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel show(Long id) {
        return candidateDao.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel update(Long id, CandidateDto candidate) {
        CandidateModel cm = candidateDao.findOne(id);
        // Update values.
        return candidateDao.save(cm);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        candidateDao.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Now you can also remove the bean definition for the `SessionFactory` reducing your `Application` to just a `main` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan("com.buhryn.interviewer.models")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------- Start Application ---------------------------");
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

So I would strongly suggest to work with the framework instead of trying to work around the framework. As that will really simplify your developer live.

### Dependencies

As a final note I would suggest removing the `spring-data-jpa` dependency from your dependencies and use the starter instead. The same goes for AspectJ use the AOP starter for that. Also jackson 1 isn't supported anymore so adding that dependency doesn't add anything

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final")
    compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you don't want @Transactional on your DAO/Repository layer, but rather let it be managed from the Service layer.

Comment: I follow all your instructions and doesn't work yet for me ): I think that the @Transactional is ignored because I used a throw new Exception(); to simulate an error.

Comment: `Exception` isn't rolledback only `RuntimeException`s (that is all explained in the reference guide and javadocs of said classes).

Comment: I tried to used that too, throw new RuntimeException(); to be explicit I used rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class, Exception.class} (One first then both) and doesn't work.

Comment: If it doesn't work you are doing the wrong things and haven't followed what ism mentioned here. Ask a new question instead of hijacking this answer with comments.

Comment: Before place a new question, @Transactional handle try/Catch ? due to I have something like: `try{ /*Actions...*/  if(null) {throw new RuntimeException();} }catch(Excepction e){ /* Error Log */  } return Boolean;`

Comment: And as mentioned you haven’t done as in the question. You are catching the exception yourself and therefor are breaking the transaction management. It doesn’t see the error and thus will commit instead of rollback.

Comment: Excelsior ! Thank you so much ! that was something that I wasn't understood very well before, but I remove the try/catch and works as expected !

Comment: Not adding try-catch is also works for me. Thank you for this useful information.