# Spring boot with spring @Transactional works without enabling transactional management

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

In my spring boot application spring @Transactional annotation works without specifying @EnableTransactionManagement explicitly.

Is there any official documentation saying that it is enabled automatically?

Or there is something else happening .... ?

btw: I'm using Spring Data JPA

Comment: Do you have spring-jdbc on your classpath? If so, spring boots autoconfiguration will create a [DataSourceTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.java) for you

Comment: Thanks for the comment @anders, can you refer to some official documentation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is enabled as long as you have `spring-tx` and some transactional resource in your application. Effectively if you are using `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, Spring Boot will configure a `DataSource` for you, start Hibernate (in the latter case) and configure transaction management.

Not all "`Enable`" annotations require to be explicitly set. When there is a reasonable amount of things that we can check to validate it makes sense to configure that for you, we'll do it. In this case, if you have a `DataSource` you must probably want to have transactions. If you have JPA (and no JTA infrastructure), you probably want a `JpaTransactionManager`). If we auto-configure that, the easiest way to use it is via `@Transactional` so we'll enable that in that case as well.

I guess you kept asking to get some sort of "official" answer, so here's one.

Comment: IMO it worths noting that having "some transactional resource in your application" is not enough to "magically" enable `@Transactional` if you don't have `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in your configuration class.

Comment: Indeed, it is tied to the auto-configuration and that's what I meant by "if we auto-configure that"

Answer (score 2):

*@SpringBootApplication* adds *@EnableAutoConfiguration* it detects *Spring Data JPA* on your classpath. According to it Spring registers PlatformTransactionManager - *JpaTransactionManager*, datasource, entitymanager, repositories.

Not sure there are precise articles, but there are proper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870146/transactional-annotation-not-working-in-spring-boot) on stack. An official spring sample [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: What about `mybatis-spring-boot-starter`?

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional annotation can work fine if the "< tx:annotation-driven/ >" tag is in your Spring XML configuration. Look at this reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html